# ViewController title color will change change color when back button clicked

Tags: iphone, swift, xcode

I have a Home viewController, and it's linked to another viewController via Segue animation (so I have also linked the home ViewController to a NavigationContoller). In the Home Viewcontroller, I have changed the title text to orange, but when I click the button that triggers the segue and then come back to the Home ViewController, the title changed color.

[Home ViewController in its normal state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYrJs.png) -
[Back button clicked in the next view and back to Home ViewController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DVgO.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you did not show the code, I don't know what is wrong with it. But here's how I always do it and it works:

Go to your storyboard file and select "Navigation Bar" under "Navigation Controller Scene" in the hierachy thingy:

[image]

Go to the Property Inspector on the right and find this item:

[image]

Set it to the desired color!

Comment: This is the code I used `self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.white self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isOpaque = true navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIIma‌​ge(), for: UIBarMetrics.default) navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage() navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = color self.navigationController!.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.orange]`   @Sweeper

Comment: @edoriggio I would try to put the above code in `viewDidAppear`. If that doesn't work, try the approached I described in the answer.

Comment: @edoriggio Don't post a bunch of code into a comment. You should provide that information in your question.

Comment: @rmaddy Yea, thanks for the tip, sorry but I am new here ... :)